# Do I need to know JSP before using web frameworks?

Tags: java, frameworks, web

In general, do I need to get comfort with JSP first before start using web framework, or is that too much time to spent on it?

If this will help, I can code in PHP and Python. Is Java is a totally new thing?

The reason I ask this is because we know those coming from ASP or VB usually can easily learn Python, and those coming from C or C++ can easily like PHP.

Any suggestion?

Updated: as suggested by sleske

> I don't understand why there are so many web framework for java with
>   different approach, and before that, I need to know what else do I
>   have to know before start, for example The difference between Java EE
>   and Tomcat server , why is there a container etc? ??? Please enlight.
>   Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, please clarify you question. Do you want to know if you need to learn JSP before using a framework like JSF, Apache Tapestry or JBoss Seam? Or do you want to know how different PHP, Python and Java are? Or what...?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't understand why there are so many web framework for java with different approach, and before that, I need to know what else do I have to know before start, for example The difference between Java EE and Tomcat server , why is there a container etc? ??? Please enlight. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question with the clarification; not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: question updated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mandatory, but if you know Servlet it would be better, of course.

In my case, I started with JSF. Some time latter I learned about Servlets, just when I needed it.

If you don't want to spend time with Servlet for while, I suggest you to do the same and try out JSF.

Some useful sites:

http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/

https://sites.google.com/site/freej2eevideotutorial/-java-server-faces-jsf-2-0-video-tutorial-jsf-2-0-video-training

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to this question(s), but:

> Is Java totally a new thing?

Java is strongly typed language, unlike PHP or Python, which are script, interpreted languages. Have you used any of the Java-like languages, ever? (C++, C#)

> do I need to get comfort with JSP first before start using web framework?

In my opinion, it is not necessary in the very begining to exhaust yourself with JSP, but it is **highly** recommended to understand [Servlets](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html), since all the frameworks are using them in one way or another. As far as the frameworks are concerned, there are plenty of them out there, and I can't help you in making the choice which one to choose.
Hope this helps a little.

Comment: C . but not for making web pages. Agreed for Servlets. Thank you

Comment: @weldan-jamili if you used C, and you are familiar with the concepts of data types, structures, stack and heap memory allocation, then you should be good to go with Java, although some book/tutorial is recommended. There are plenty of those too, you can take your pick, or search for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is necessary to have at least a basic understanding of JSPs, as most of the Java  frameworks are based around this technology.

As Less said Servlets are important to understand. A JSP page is basically a markup language that generates a Java code that outputs HTML. Servlet technology is at the core of this.